# How to install Nuget package (.nupkg file) in Delphi IDE without using the GetIt Package Manager?

Tags: delphi, nuget, tedgebrowser

I am trying to use the `TEdgeBrowser` component in RAD Studio 10.2.

I want to apply that component by following the guide document below:

[Using TEdgeBrowser Component and Changes to the TWebBrowser Component](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Using_TEdgeBrowser_Component_and_Changes_to_the_TWebBrowser_Component)

The document uses the component after installing the package through Edge search in Getit Package Manager.

RAD Studio 10.2 GetIt was unable to find `TEdgeBrowser`:

[image: No Result Found Image]

I downloaded the package from the Nuget site, and try to install the package manually.

So I downloaded the nupkg file from the Nuget download link:

[Microsoft.Web.WebView2 Download Link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Web.WebView2)

In the document, the description of the component and package installation is completed by adding the downloaded DLL file to the executable file path.

How do I manually install packages and use components in the Delphi IDE using nupkg files?

I tried to install it using `GetItCmd.exe`, `Nuget.exe`, etc, but there aren't enough guides on how to do this, so I'm asking the question.

I downloaded `Microsoft.Web.WebView2` 0.9.488 package from the Nuget site, but it doesn't matter if I use the latest version.

Comment: The `TEdgeBrowser` component was introduced in 10.4, it does not exist in 10.2.  And you can't install Nuget packages into the Delphi IDE.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.
10.2 WebView2 is not searched by Getit.

I am trying to import the WebView2.tlb file via ImportComponent. Currently, an error occurs when loading the registry, but we are searching for that error.

Comment: What is the actual error? Is the TLB registered with Windows before you import it?

Comment: I didn't know about the process of registering the tlb file in the registry. Let's check the registry registration part. Thank you for good information.

Answer (score 0):

I can use the edgebrowser in Delphi 10/11.
Use the import component / dll it can work well.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Vm4x.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).